# Android Studio throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When i am trying to open my android studio it throws Following errors . I attached the actual screen-shot . I tried to disconnect the INTERNET and then open android studio even i un-install the android studio completely and install the latest on but still it throws the same error . 
Please help me to resolve this error .

Thanks in advance.

> Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Error Image

[image]